# Undefined variable error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a function in which I read and display in an excel like spread sheet (used the spreadJS library) on a tab. Although it works fine on Ubuntu Chromium, when I run it on Firefox or Chrome I get an error message:

```
TypeError: spread is undefined
var metricsSheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
```

This is the function:

```
    requirejs.config({
        shim: {
            "spreadjs": {
                deps: ["jquery"],
            }
        },
        paths: {
            "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min",
            "spreadjs": "http://cdn.wijmo.com/spreadjs/jquery.wijmo.wijspread.3.20143.15.min",
        },
    });
    require(["jquery", "spreadjs"], function () {
            $("#ss").wijspread();
            spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");  
    });


     function initExcel(){
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Code/python/csv/outputMetrics.csv",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data){ // on succes loop through the lines of CSV

                // and pass data into spread sheet.
                    var allLines = data.split('\n');
                    var metricsSheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
                    // set column width of columns
                    metricsSheet.setColumnWidth (1,400);
                    metricsSheet.setColumnWidth (2,300);
                    for (var i=0; i<allLines.length; i++) {
                        var data = allLines[i].split(';');
                        metricsSheet.setValue(i+1, 1, data[0]);
                        metricsSheet.setValue(i+1, 2, data[1]);
                    }
                    spread.isPaintSuspended(false);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error reading CSV or passing data to Excel");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

What can it be the reason that Javascript shows this error?

Comment: in your code I can't see a definition for `spread` so this error is obvious for me.

Comment: @Mritunjay "used the spreadJS library"

Comment: Well, did that library load correctly?

Comment: @dkar: show us where does the `spread` variable come from, it should clear things up a little bit

Comment: Answer edited with the code part that I declare spread variable.

Comment: Seriously now? You downvote cause I didnt include the definition of spread? Isn't it expected that I declare it..

Comment: where do you declare that `var spread`

Comment: spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");

Comment: Ok, try to declare `var spread` outside of all methods and top

Comment: I did that but I get the same problem. It must be browser related cause it works ok in Chromium.

Comment: It has to be related with the loading of the libraries. I guess Firefox loads the libraries in a different order.

Comment: *"Isn't it expected that I declare it..."* – A ton of questions here are caused by trivial stuff like this. We cannot assume *any* competence or implied environment on your part. – Is that exactly how you declare `spread`? Why isn't the code that depends on `spread` *inside* the `require` block? There is absolutely no guarantee that `spread` is declared before your `initExcel` function executes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're seeing timing problems, and your code inside `initExcel` is executed before `spread` is loaded and created. There's absolutely no guarantee that `spread` will be available before you need it; it all depends on luck, network speeds and caching.

Define any code which has dependencies *inside* the `require` block which ensures its dependencies are met:

```
require(["jquery", "spreadjs"], function () {
        $("#ss").wijspread();
        var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");  

        function initExcel(){ ... }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helps and I learned something new. If I define my code inside require it works fine but only when I don't include the declaration of the function (initExcel ). If I do I get an error undefined function.

Comment: Well, probably some other code is depending on the *global* existence of that function. This is getting a bit broad, as it requires us to know your entire application and what depends on what. You "simply" need to write your app in a way that it can be lazy-loaded through `require`, not using any implicit global dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `spread` has not been declared yet.
According to [SpreadJS Documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadHClientUG/modules.html)
you are missing the call to the spreadJS library, where spread is defined.
So you should just need to add:

```
$("#yourDOMelementID").wijspread();
var spread = $("#yourDOMelementID").wijspread("spread");
```